# save file from data in nodejs

Tags: node.js, file

i have this object from multer lib

```
var myfiledata = { fieldname: 'file_comic',
  originalname: 'leoncino.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  buffer: <Buffer ff d8 ff e2 02 1c 49 43 43 5f 50 52 4f 46 49 4c 45 00 01 01 00 00 02 0c 6c 63 6d 73 02 10 00 00 6d 6e 74 72 52 47 42 20 58 59 5a 20 07 dc 00 01 00 19 ... >,
  size: 74448 }
```

I would save this file on harddisk

I would like to use a statement similar to this one

```
fs.writeFile("./test.png", myfiledata.buffer, 'binary');
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31592726/how-to-store-a-file-with-file-extension-with-multer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the buffer data to writeStream. If you want the file to be saved at different path, provide the path in `fs.createWriteStream('./uploads/' + req.file.originalname)`:

```
app.post('/upload', multer.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    var fileWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(req.file.originalname);
    fileWriteStream.on('finish', () => {
        console.log('file saved successfully');
        res.send({ message: 'file saved successfully' })
    })
    fileWriteStream.end(req.file.buffer)
})
```